# Android send ints and strings to mysql using httppost

Tags: android, mysql, post

I'm trying to send data which includes strings and ints to mysql using httppost, but it seems I need to use basicnamevaluepairs which only takes strings. The best idea to solve this that I've seen has been just to turn the Int into a string.  But I want to store the data as an Int in the database so that I can perform order by operations properly.  I tried overriding the basicnamevaluepairs method but it won't return anything but a string.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can create a json object and send. Or you can add a check in your server

Comment: Thanks very simple solution, but saved me a lot of trouble:)